# md-grid-list and ngAnimate dont seem to be working together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ng-animate

I need to make something similar to the good old masonry animations like **angular-masonry** (and its jquery predecessor) but I'm using **angular material** and their `grid-list`. Does this negate being able to use `ngAnimate` in the `ngRepeat`?

I made [a codepen](https://codepen.io/SuddenDevelopment/pen/PKmwwZ) to play with it:

Comment: Was additional information are you looking for in the codepen?  Is your question really about the animation that you want to occur when the "resort" button is clicked?  Right now there is no animation; would I be correct in assuming you are trying to figure out how to apply an animation there?